# Merging GitLab Merge Requests Manually

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I want to merge all my existing merge requests manually. Let's say these are my existing merge requests:

```
1) feature1 --> master
2) feature2 --> master
```

For some business requirements, I need to merge all existing merge request branches to an intermediate branch called `integration` on my local. And then I need to merge `integration` with `master.`.And on my workstation, what I'm doing is:

```
$ git clone ...
$ git fetch
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b integration

# Rebase feature1 with integration and merge
$ git checkout feature1
$ git rebase integration
$ git checkout integration
$ git merge feature1

# Rebase feature2 with integration and merge
$ git checkout feature2
$ git rebase integration
$ git checkout integration
$ git merge feature2

# Merge integration to master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge integration
$ git push origin master
```

But when I check merge requests on GitLab, I only see the first one as merged. Second pull request still open even if the merge is successful.

Comment: *manually with a cron … job* Well, if it's a cron job, it's hardly `manually`. *grabbing all waiting merge requests, merge them* How do you perform merge? Using `git merge` or Gitlab API? If it's `git merge` do you push merges back to Gitlab?

Comment: Sorry for misleading explanation. There are some more complex processes to determine which pull requests are waiting for merge. Actually, that part is not important, you can forget about the Jenkins job and imagine that I'm locally pulling all merge request branches to my workstation and merging them to a branch called `integration-branch`. After this, I'm merging `integration-branch` to `master` on my local repo. Lastly, I'm pushing `integration-branch` and `master` branches to GitLab. I'm not using GitLab API and handling all these operations with just git commands (like `git merge`). @phd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebasing `feature2` on top of integration is most likely creating a situation where none of the commits on your `feature2` branch end up in the `integration` branch.

Remember that rebase does not modify the existing commits, but replaces them with new commits.

Try this:

```
# Rebase feature2 with integration and merge
$ git checkout feature2
$ git rebase integration

# This will update your pull request so gitlab can detect the merge
$ git push origin feature2

$ git checkout integration
$ git merge feature2
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the correct answer. Unfortunately, after trying your solution I figured out another problem in my design. Merging of `feature1` and `feature2` to `integration` is happening in two different Jenkins job, parallelly.  Because of this, when I rebase `feature2` with the integration branch, `feature1`'s commits may not be in the integration branch yet. But of course this is another story and your answer is definitely answering my first question. Thank you.